# AngularJS / Replace Sorting within ng-click and ng-show with custom method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I have a set of table columns. Each column can be sorted straight and in reverse. Up until now, we were doing that sorting inside each `ng-click` and `ng-show`, like so:

**HTML**

```
<a style="color:black" href="" ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse; changeSortType('id')">
  Group id
  <span ng-show="sortType == 'id' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
  <span ng-show="sortType == 'id' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
</a></th>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
  $scope.sortType = 'count';
  $scope.sortReverse = true;

  $scope.changeSortType = function (sortType){
    $scope.sortType = sortType;
  };

  $scope.itemSortValue = function (item) {
    return Service.sort(item, $scope.sortType)
  };
```

**Now we want to replace this with a method, that does the same so we can diminish the amount of code in the HTML.**

I don't know how to do this exactly in **AngularJS**. Whatever I do doesn't work. I have also seen a couple of answers but they don't work, or I am doing something wrong. **COuld you please help me with the code.**

Comment: what you want to replace with method?can you show what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to remove the sorting withing the ng-click, with a custom Method. Meaning move all the logic, to the controller like so:. From this ng-click="sortReverse = !sortReverse; changeSortType('id')" => ng-click=changeSortType('id')". The same principle for the ng-show as well. This is a work task, and we have a large amount of table, so we want to remove the logic from each column in the HTML to the controlle. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: sortReverse is scope variable?

Comment: I believe so. This code is pretty old, and we are in the process of cleaning it up. I am also not very good with angularjs. So, sorry if I say stupid stuff.

Comment: If you need code from a directive or a service tell me what you want and I can find it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `<a>` element remove `sortReverse = !sortReverse;`  from ng-click and add `$scope.sortReverse= !$scope.sortReverse` it in the first line of method changeSortType;

and for ng-show create and method

```
$scope.myMethod = function (id, reverse){
    return id && reverse;
  };
```

and change html to

```
 <span ng-show="myMethod('id',!sortReverse)" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
  <span ng-show="myMethod('id',sortReverse)" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
```

Comment: I have a question. As I said I have multiple table columnns. LEt's say, "id, numbers, animals etc". Do I need to pass those as arguments to the custom method as well, and if yes how? Like so: $scope.myMethod = function(id, number, animals, reverse) { return ????}. I know I am a noob but please bear with me..

Comment: its okay...yes its like a normal method which takes the argument if your method needs those argument then you can pass them and define your method signature according to that

Comment: I tried it but I get an error sortReserve is not defined. It refers to the addition you mentioned in changeSortType function.

Comment: it means its not a scope variable can you add complete html code and corresponding controller?

Comment: It is not the complete files as both of them are 300 lines long, but the parts we most likely need are there...

Comment: I just made changes to answer sortReverse was scope variable and we need to access it using $scope in our controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181321/discussion-between-nawnit-sen-and-dimitris-efstathiadis).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code .

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<div class="jumbotron bg-dark" style="border-radius: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <h1 class="text-center" style="color:azure;">Table Sort</h1> 
</div>
 <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-click="orderByMe('Name')" style="cursor: pointer;">Name <i class="fa fa-sort-desc" style="font-size:15px;color: whitesmoke" ng-if=" toggleCursor == 'desc'"></i>  <i class="fa fa-sort-asc" ng-if=" toggleCursor == 'asc'"></i></th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;">City </th>
        <th style="cursor: pointer;"> Country</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat=" data in myData  | orderBy:myOrderBy">
       <th>{{data.Name}}</th>
       <th>{{data.City}}</th>
       <th>{{data.Country}}</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS File**

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("https://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data.records;
        });
        $scope.toggleCursor = 'desc';
        $scope.myOrderBy = 'Name';
        $scope.orderByMe = function(sort) {
             $scope.myOrderBy = sort;
             $scope.sortArry = $scope.myData.sort();
             if($scope.toggleCursor == 'desc')
                {
                    $scope.toggleCursor = 'asc';
                    $scope.myOrderBy = $scope.sortArry;
                }        
             else
             {
                 $scope.toggleCursor = 'desc';
                 $scope.myOrderBy =  $scope.sortArry.reverse();
             }
        }
    });
```